# What do the FireBug DOM colors mean?

Tags: javascript, dom, firebug

I'm confused with these colors.
I noticed there are 4 colors showing in the left hand column of FireBug DOM tree:

1. Bold black
2. Black
3. Bold green
4. Green

In the right hand column:

1. Blue
2. Red
3. Bold green
4. Green
5. Multiple color elements representing object structures.

What do this colors represent? And why, e.g, I can access window.document.URL and I can't access window.document.body in Console even though they are both in the "not-bold black" category in the DOM tree?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging into it a little further I got the answer:

In the left column:

> Black are properties and green are
>   methods. Bold means the member was
>   declared "by the user" meaning the
>   members aren't from the default
>   javascript/DOM framework.

In the right column:

> Numbers are blue, strings are red.
>   Objects appear as a "instance preview"
>   in which the type name and the member
>   names are green and the member values
>   are gray

Answer (score 13):

Here is the correct answer.

```
Bold Black                   Objects
Black                        DOM objects
get in gray                  "Getter" functions
Bold green                   User functions
Green                        DOM functions
Bold Red                     Constructor functions
```

Check out the [link](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/DOM_Panel) for more information. 
Further info in the FAQ [link](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/FAQ#What_do_the_different_colors_of_the_variables_mean.3F).

Answer (score 1):

From http://getfirebug.com/dom.html

> Objects are color coded so that HTML
>   elements, numbers, strings, functions,
>   arrays, objects, and nulls are all
>   easy to distinguish.

But I can't be bothered to lookup which color represents what. With this info I bet you can make that out yourself

Comment: Thanks but this link as the first I saw on google when I searched.