# firebug:object inspection

Tags: object, firebug, inspection

In firebug it is so easy and very handy to inspect an object.

However, I don't have any clue about the color code used there.

Some properties are in red, some others in green, some in black, some with bold font, etc...

When you hover over some properties, they change to blue

Anyone can explain this or give a reference.

Thanks

*I am using version 1.7 with FireFox 4.0.1*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[What do the FireBug DOM colors mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754954/what-do-the-firebug-dom-colors-mean)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/DOM_Panel

[image]

Comment: thank you so much
I could have marked this one as right answer too

Answer (score 0):

its hard to find information about that. Maybe this can help you: http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/FAQ#What_do_the_different_colors_of_the_variables_mean.3F

Bold Black are objects

Not so bold Black are DOM objects

Get in Gray in front means "getter"

Bold green are user functions

Not so bold Green are DOM functions

Bold Red are constructor functions

Comment: Thank you 
I really helped to get it straight from the horse's mouth